# Ubuntu 14.04 Live works perfect, but after installation nothing but the keyboard works?

Tags: 14.04, wireless, live-usb, bluetooth, thinkpad

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad T510 with an i7 core and 6 gigs of RAM. When I boot Ubuntu from the USB stick Live it works fine, but when I install it, the trackpad doesn't work, the screen resolution is off, the Bluetooth and WiFi don't work, and I can't change anything. I'm new to Ubuntu, and Linux for that matter, and I can't figure it out. I installed it on my friends Lenovo ThinkPad T410 and it worked fine in Live and after installed. I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Linux world. Sorry you met a little bump there. Not sure what went wrong, but try these first before attempting a reinstall:

1. Plug your laptop to a wired internet connection and boot up. Once
   booted, press "Ctrl+Alt+F1". If your built-in keyboard doesn't work,
   try using an external keyboard.
2. Login into the system by typing the username and password you set during installation.
3. Execute the following in sequence: `sudo apt-get update`(this will update your software repository from the net and check for updates); then `sudo apt-get upgrade` (this will perform the update if any); and just in case, do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` too (similar as before, but just as an additional measure in case previous update has conflicting packages this should resolve it automatically).
4. Finally do a reboot by executing `sudo reboot`.

The above are basic maintenance procedure performed through terminal, if interested you can read more on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Maintenance_commands

Best of luck!

Comment: I thank you for your help, and I'm sure that your instructions will work, but my computer will not connect over Ethernet for one reason or another. Ctrl+Alt+F1 at the login screen or after loging in, does not work. It blacks out the screen. I tried the commands in Terminal after pluging in the network cable and that made no difference. I'm having trouble installing Windows 7 which I deleted a while back while playing with Niresh. If you could point me in the right direction with reinstalling windows, as I need it for school, that'd be awesome, too. Thanks.

Comment: That's unfortunate... alright here goes in sequence, read through first before doing:

Comment: 1. Start by backing up your important files. You mentioned the Ubuntu Live USB works fine, so let's do it with this. Boot it and copy all files you want to keep to another USB. If the partition where Windows originally was still exist, I advise backing up the entire partition too.  2. Since you have rescued all your important files, now we will just wipe out your entire hard disk and start on a clean slate. Installing Windows 7 should be easy this way. Just follow instruction by Microsoft on this page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-my/windows/installing-reinstalling-windows#1TC=windows-7

Comment: 3. Once Windows 7 is installed, boot in then download and install back all the necessary driver for your laptop model. Or you can always do the driver googling and downloading from another computer first.   Hope that helps.

Comment: That should be it. Hope that help. Good luck!